Confusion using thingsspeak in MATLAB(How to turn on relevant lamps depending on signal recieved from thingsspeak)
We have sensors connected on power grid lines that will tell the status wether there is any issue . We are trying to use thingsspeak and we performed some initial working which is shown in link below
https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/170371-sample-app-for-power-line-status
Manually our relevant lamps are working but we want to turn them on depending on signal recieved from thingsspeak. How we can proceed further?
Channel id is 543172
